# Sympy suddently does not work together with TFQ

Tags: programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, tfq

I work with tensorflow-quantum and use `sympy` for parameter updating.

Suddenly, without (manually) updating or changing anything this error comes up:

```
  File "/home/eli/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_quantum/core/serialize/serializer.py", line 93, in _symbol_extractor
    if isinstance(expr, sympy.mul.Mul):

AttributeError: module 'sympy' has no attribute 'mul'
```

Has anyone had this before? Do you have any suggestions for what I can try to fix this?

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
TFQ version 0.4.0
Sympy version 1.8

the error occurs when I build my PQC layer:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string), 
                        tfq.layers.PQC(circuit, [cirq.Z(q) for q in builder.get_valid_outputs()]),
                        ], name = model_type)
```

and it worked like this a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to add a little more context to your answer: TensorFlow-Quantum 0.4.0 has an explicit version dependency on `sympy==1.5.0` in the `setup.py` module [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/v0.4.0/release/setup.py#L53), which should have been installed when you first installed TFQ. It's possible that other python pip packages may have overriden or upgraded the sympy version since then. Using something like `pip list | grep sympy` will show which version of sympy you have installed in case you see breakages like this going forward with sympy (or other packages + dependencies) .

Also one final note: TensorFlow Quantum 0.5.0 has been released and does also depend on sympy==1.5.0 which you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/master/release/setup.py#L54) .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with a downgrade of sympy to version 1.6.1
It seems that tfq 0.4.0 needs that corresponding version to work properly